# How can I redirect users to different pages based on using private routing

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple react project with 5 pages (Home, Login, Create, Update, Delete).

When my project loads automatically, my project should stay on the Home Page component ('/'). The user should only see a menu like this: Home|Create|Update|Delete.

NB if the user tries to access pages like Create|Update|Delete... he or she should be prompted to login first and for successful login he or she should be able to navigate to each menu item.

I don't want to use the fake authentication, but I should have a default user used to login. Please help since I am new to react.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Burner from "./components/Burner"; 
import Header from "./components/Header"; 
import Footer from "./components/Footer"; 

class App extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <div className="container"> <Burner /> <Header /> <Footer /> </div> );
   }
 }
 export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) for that.

This module will allow you to redirect and route the user to specific pages based on what you need.

In case you need to redirect the user out for login, you can use something like this:

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, exact, path, authenticated }) => (
    <Route
        exact={exact}
        path={path}
        render={props =>
            authenticated ? (
                React.createElement(component, props)
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/login",
                        state: { from: props.location }
                    }}
                />
            )
        }
    />
);
```

You can then use `PrivateRoute` for redirecting the user if it's not logged in:

```js
import { Login } from './Login';
import { Create } from './Home';

    // authenticated will be true if the user is authenticated
    const AppComponent = ({ authenticated }) => (
     <Router>
      <>
      <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/login/" component={Login} />
       <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
       <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path="/create"
        component={Create}
        authenticated={authenticated}
       />
      </Switch>
      </>
     </Router>
    );
```

You can take a look to the DOCs here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start